# Spring webflux Netty: How to expose proto as json endpoints without duplication of code?

Tags: json, protocol-buffers, spring-webflux

Use-case:

Developers/I, want to only implement a Protobuf implementation (binary protocol). However, I need a way to add config, so, the same implementation is exposed as rest/json api as well -- **without code duplication**.

I have proto endpoints exposed. I also want consumers to **post** json equivalent of those proto objects and return/receive json equivalent of the results with type info (Pojo?). The type info helps with OpenAPI / Swagger documentation too!

What are the most elegant/simple ways to achieve that without code duplication?

Any example github code that achieves that would be helpful.

**Note: This is for webflux & netty** - no tomcat.

ProtobufJsonFormatHttpMessageConverter  - works for tomcat, does not work for netty. A working example code would be great.

[image]

Comment: Did you solve the issue?, I too ended up with same issue, when I add spring-boot-starter-web dependency and enable `ProtobufJsonFormatHttpMessageConverter` it works, when I see the logs it uses webmvc rather than webflux, a pure weblux netty server does not work.

Comment: @KarthikPrasad, Nope. I stooped down to making custom pojo SearchResponse. I believe it may need custom spring converters, that  automatically engages for application/json & application/protobuf, and return SearchResponse-json or binary respectively.

Comment: This is shame that spring team does not support this even after 3 years

Answer (score 0):

I was messing around with this and ended up with this. Nothing else worked for me.
Using protov3 and setting a protobuf like this

```
syntax = "proto3";
option java_package = "com.company";
option java_multiple_files = true;

message CreateThingRequest {
...

message CreateThingResponse {
....
```

I can scan for the protobuf files by setting app.protoPath in my application.properties

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.google.common.reflect.ClassPath;
import com.google.protobuf.Message;
import com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.codec.ServerCodecConfigurer;
import org.springframework.http.codec.json.Jackson2JsonDecoder;
import org.springframework.http.codec.json.Jackson2JsonEncoder;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.config.WebFluxConfigurer;


@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebFluxConfigurer {

  @Value("${app.protoPath:com.}")
  private String protoPath;

  @Override
  public void configureHttpMessageCodecs(ServerCodecConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonEncoder(
        new Jackson2JsonEncoder(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json().serializerByType(
            Message.class, new JsonSerializer<Message>() {
              @Override
              public void serialize(Message value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
                String str = JsonFormat.printer().omittingInsignificantWhitespace().print(value);
                gen.writeRawValue(str);
              }
            }
        ).build())
    );

    final ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    Map<Class<?>, JsonDeserializer<?>> deserializers = new HashMap<>();
    try {
      for (final ClassPath.ClassInfo info : ClassPath.from(loader).getTopLevelClasses()) {
        if (info.getName().startsWith(protoPath)) {
          final Class<?> clazz = info.load();

          if (!Message.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
            continue;
          }
          @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") final Class<Message> proto = (Class<Message>) clazz;

          final JsonDeserializer<Message> deserializer = new CustomJsonDeserializer() {
            @Override
            public Class<Message> getDeserializeClass() {
              return proto;
            }
          };
          deserializers.put(proto, deserializer);
        }
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    configurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonDecoder(new Jackson2JsonDecoder(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json().deserializersByType(deserializers).build()));
  }

  private abstract static class CustomJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Message> {
    abstract Class<? extends Message> getDeserializeClass();

    @Override
    public Message deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
      Message.Builder builder = null;
      try {
        builder = (Message.Builder) getDeserializeClass()
            .getDeclaredMethod("newBuilder")
            .invoke(null);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
      JsonFormat.parser().merge(jp.getCodec().readTree(jp).toString(), builder);
      return builder.build();
    }
  }
}
```

Then I just use the object types in the returns;

```
@PostMapping(
    path = "/things",
    consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, "application/x-protobuf"},
    produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, "application/x-protobuf"})
Mono<CreateThingResponse> createThing(@RequestBody CreateThingRequest request);
```

With https://github.com/innogames/springfox-protobuf you can get the responses to show in swagger but the requests still aren't showing for me.

You'll have to excuse the messy Java I'm a little rusty.

Comment: Thanks for the great effort -- avoiding code dup is great! I hope Spring guys step in and fix, so it becomes easy, i.e avoid reflection, class loader etc. 
 Added an issue in springframework, https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/25457

Comment: I had someone use this and found if you don't limit the protopath to only the location of your protobufs it can cause an exception on some classes.

    `@Value("${app.protoPath:com.}") <- limit to com.company.product.models.v1.`
    `private String protoPath;`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding ProtoEncoder in your WebFlux config:

```
@EnableWebFlux
public class MyConfig implements WebFluxConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureHttpMessageCodecs(ServerCodecConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.customCodecs().register(new ProtobufEncoder());
    }
}
```

Then in your request mapping return the proto object:

```
@GetMapping (produces = "application/x-protobuf")
public MyProtoObject lookup() {
 return new MyProtoObject();
}
```

Furthermore, if you want to serialize the proto object into JSON and return String, then have a look at `com.googlecode.protobuf-java-format:protobuf-java-format` library and `JsonFormat::printToString` capability (https://code.google.com/archive/p/protobuf-java-format/):

```
@GetMapping
public String lookup() {
 return new JsonFormat().printToString(new MyProtoObj());
}
```

Comment: This looks short and sweet. Will test this proto+json sometime.

Answer (score -1):

I needed to support json and the following code helped

```
@Bean
public WebFluxConfigurer webFluxConfigurer() {

    return new WebFluxConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void configureHttpMessageCodecs(ServerCodecConfigurer configurer) {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
                    .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
                    .configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false)
                    .registerModule(new ProtobufModule());
            configurer.customCodecs().register(new Jackson2JsonEncoder(mapper));
            configurer.customCodecs().register(new Jackson2JsonDecoder(mapper));
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: Does this convert java protobuf classes to equivalent json automatically? Do you have a simple example in github?

Comment: I used this code when receiving rest API and wanted that the framework will convert it to a POJO automatically (including protobuf POJO)  , sorry don't have an example prepared

Answer (score -2):

Since version `4.1` spring provides `org.springframework.http.converter.protobuf.ProtobufHttpMessageConverter` for reading and writing protos as Json.

However, If you are using Spring 5.x and Protobuf 3.x there is `org.springframework.http.converter.protobuf.ProtobufJsonFormatHttpMessageConverter` for more explicit conversion of Json.

This documentation should help you:

1. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/protobuf/ProtobufHttpMessageConverter.html
2. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/protobuf/ProtobufJsonFormatHttpMessageConverter.html